# Alignment of column names and its corresponding rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `CSV file` which is very messy in terms of column and row alignment. In the first cell, all column names are stated, but they do not align with the rows beneath. So when I load this CSV in `python using pandas`
[image: see picture 1]

I do not get a clean dataframe

[image: see picture 2]

In the below picture, there is an example of how it should look like with the columns separated and matching the rows.

[image: picture 3]

---

Some details:

Few lines of raw CSV file:

```
Columns:
VMName;"Cluster";"time";"AvgValue";"MinValue";"MaxValue";"MetricId";"MemoryMB";"CpuMHz";"NumCpu"
Rows:
ITLT4301;1;"1-5-2018";976439;35059255;53842;6545371441;3235864;95200029;"MemActive";"4096";"0";"0"
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_location, sep=";")
```

Output when loading the dataframe in python:

```
VMName;"Cluster";"time";"AvgValue";"MinValue";"MaxValue";"MetricId";"MemoryMB";"CpuMHz";"NumCpu",,,
ITLT4301;1;"1-5-2018";976439,35059255  53842,6545371441 3235864,"95200029 MemActive""   4096"" 0""                                                  0"""
```

Desired output:

```
VMName   Cluster time    AvgValue MinValue MaxValue MetricId   MemoryMB CpuMHz   
ITLT4301 1       1-5-201 976439   35059255 53842    6545371441 95200029 MemActive

NumCpu
4096
```

Hopefully this clears up the topic and problem a bit. Desired output is a well-organized data frame where the columns match the rows based on separater sign ";"

Comment: I do not see any images? Anyways, it is always better to just put code/tables, etc as text, so people can just copy them and use them in their answers to your question.

Comment: How do you load the file in pandas? Have you specified `sep=';'`? As a new user you really should read [ask]. Specifically what is needed here is: a few lines of the csv file **as text** so that we know exactly as it is formatted including separators and eventual quotes, the code you used to load and produce the output, the produced output and the expected output. Please be sure to be consistent and avoid to change the name of the columns unless it is explicitely wanted and described.

Comment: @NOhs Please see the text examples provided in the answer below.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Please see the text examples provided in the answer below

Comment: @BoGo: Are really `Columns:` and `Rows:` in the csv file?

Comment: @SergeBallesta the first row in the csv file represent the column names seperated by a ; sign (VMName;"Cluster";"time";"AvgValue";"MinValue";"MaxValue";"MetricId";"MemoryMB";"CpuMHz";"NumCpu"). The rows represent the values and are separated in the same way. However, when I load the CSV file with pandas, the columns and rows are not aligning, hence the data frame looks very messy and unclear.

Comment: Unless you show some lines from the csv file *as they appear in a text editor* like notepad, notepad++ or vi, I will not be able to reproduce. I do not want additional comments, just the text from the file.

Comment: This is how the csv file appears in a plain text document (first 3 lines where the first line are the column names)

"VMName;""Cluster"";""time"";""AvgValue"";""MinValue"";""MaxValue"";""MetricId"";""MemoryMB"";""CpuMHz"";""NumCpu"""   
"ITLT4301;1;""1-5-2018"";976439" 35059255;53842 6545371441;3235864 "95200029;""MemActive"";""4096"";""0"";""0"""
"ITLT4301;1;""1-5-2018"";98" 9443749608104;29 3435452286154;673 "067568681366;""CpuUsageMHz"";""0"";""5600"";""2"""

Comment: Yep, I could reproduce! Let me some time to understand what is that mess of double quotes and propose a fix...

Answer (score 1):

Your input data file is not a standard csv file. The correct way would be to fix the previous step in order to get a normal csv file instead of a mess of double quotes preventing any decent  csv parser to correctly extract data.

As a workaround, it is possible to remove the initial and terminating double quote, remove any doubled double quote, and split every line on semi-column ignoring any remaining double quote. Optionnaly, you could also try to just remove any double quote and split the lines on ';'. It really depends on what values you expect.

A possible code could be:

```
def split_line(line):
    '''split a line on ; after stripping white spaces, the initial and terminating "
       doubles double quotes are also removed'''
    return line.strip()[1:-1].replace('""', '').split(';')

with open('file.dat') as fd:
    cols = split_line(next(fd))                # extract column names from header line
    data = [split_line(line) for line in fd]   # process data lines
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)      # build a dataframe from that
```

With that input:

```
"VMName;""Cluster"";""time"";""AvgValue"";""MinValue"";""MaxValue"";""MetricId"";""MemoryMB"";""CpuMHz"";""NumCpu"""
"ITLT4301;1;""1-5-2018"";976439" 35059255;53842 6545371441;3235864 "95200029;""MemActive"";""4096"";""0"";""0"""
"ITLT4301;1;""1-5-2018"";98" 9443749608104;29 3435452286154;673 "067568681366;""CpuUsageMHz"";""0"";""5600"";""2"""
```

It gives:

```
     VMName Cluster      time           AvgValue          MinValue  \
0  ITLT4301       1  1-5-2018   976439" 35059255  53842 6545371441   
1  ITLT4301       1  1-5-2018  98" 9443749608104  29 3435452286154   

            MaxValue     MetricId MemoryMB CpuMHz NumCpu  
0  3235864 "95200029    MemActive     4096      0      0  
1  673 "067568681366  CpuUsageMHz        0   5600      2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code, it returns the desired output. However, I noticed that some of the column values do not match any of the column names, as you can see in the output we have two separate numbers at "AvgValue", "MinValue", and "MaxValue". Is it possible to delete the largest numbers in these two columns. So in column "AvgValue" only the value 976439 should of row 0 should be returned. In the column "MinValue" only the value 53852 should be returned and in the column "MaxValue" only the value 3235864 should be returned. In all these columns the values on the right should be removed.

Comment: @BoGo: I cannot know how this file was produced nor what it is supposed to contain. But the basics are there: you have to manually process each line. It should not be too hard to write additional processing to fix some of the fields. But my advice is still to fix the step that produced that @#&! file...